# Custom two-factor authentication in WCF

Tags: .net, wcf, wcf-security, authentication, two-factor-authentication

Is it possible to implement two-factor (or multi-factor) custom authentication in WCF?
For example, I want to authenticate client using two different credential types:

1) User enter login and password

2) WCF Service validates login + password

3) If previous step is successful, server returns secret query (or OTP password number)

4) User enters answer for the received query and sends it to server

5) If answer is correct - user is authenticated on server. He can execute server methods.

Authenticated user has security token. On next server call client sends only server security token without explicit credentials.

I found only one reference about it on msdn - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms788756.aspx

> In .NET Framework 3.5, client messages can contain multiple tokens of
>   a given type, as well as tokens of different types.
>
> This feature enables a number of scenarios, including the following:
>
> Incremental claim sending. All operations on a service might require a
>   set of claims to be present, but some operations might require
>   additional claims. Instead of using separate issued tokens for each
>   operation, the client can obtain one issued token with the initial set
>   of claims and use another issued token with the rest of the claims
>   required for the operation being called.
>
> Multifactor authentication. When the client must collect issued tokens
>   from multiple issuers or issued tokens with different sets of claims
>   before being allowed to perform an operation. WCF considers the issued
>   token to be a token type, so this scenario requires the ability to
>   have two supporting issued tokens in the message.

But there are no real-working examples how to implement it :(
I can only authenticate using custom user credential.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do that.  Two common ways i can think of are,

1. Active Directory Authentication - you know how it works
2. Certificate Authentication  - The Host will have a Certificate Store.  Certificate supplied from Client will have to be present in the store.  If yes then pass, else fail.

The latter can be used in Business partner communication OR cross machine calls where its better to enforce another layer of security.  The binding could be of WebServiceBinding (WS Binding) OR NetTCPBinding

Lot many tutorials are available on creating Certificates and its working.  Please post if you are stuck.

Comment: Thank you! I know about AD and certificate authentication - it's very easy. But I want to use custom authentication using TWO (or more) different custom credentials. For example using Smart Card or Biometric scanner.

It's necessary to authenticate user by different ways at the same time.

Comment: Please check if these are of use.                                http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163434.aspx, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb905527.aspx